# Crystal Reports & SQL Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, crystal-reports

We have a windows 2003 server with crystal reports running on this, that ties to a sql db. Yesterday afternoon all reports that I was trying to run suddenly started freezing. I thought initially it was device specific and it was my pc and tried several other devices. Then one of my analysts noticed he couldn't run some standard Thursday reports which also froze .. etc.. Where does the error log for each of these reports write to so I can investigate the root cause?

Comment: you can check windows event viewer..

Comment: I did and there isn't anything sticking out that something is broken besides a cms issue that I resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Running slowly will not necessarily produce an error. The best thing for you to do in this situation is run the SQL used in your reports directly against SQL server from management studio, this way you have a whole host of performance monitoring options, you will also get a better feel of what the issue could be. Continue to troubleshoot different factors procedurally and you should find the issue.

Comment: Its not running slowly, its not running, and fails immediately on submit of a refresh of a reports parameters.

Comment: If it's suddenly stopped working then this probably isn't a programming issue and would be more at home on super user or something.